# How to preserve aspect ratio of overlay image in Fresco

Tags: android, image, fresco, scaletype

I am trying to set the scale type of an overlay image in Fresco. But there is no field in the SimpleDraweeView to set the scaletype of its overlay image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fresco currently does not support to set the scale type in XML.
You can wrap your overlay Drawable in a `ScaleTypeDrawable`:

```
ScaleTypeDrawable scaledOverlayDrawable = new ScaleTypeDrawable(overlayDrawable, scaleType);
```

Since API 24 you can also set a custom drawable in XML. If you target versions earlier than that (which I guess you do), you have to set the overlay in Java.

Maybe we will add support for setting a scale type some time in the future. Pull requests are also welcome :)